# How to package native dependencies to the container filesystem in Quarkus

Tags: dependencies, containers, quarkus, sapjco3

I am building an application using Quarkus 3.1.0.Final and my requirement is to copy libsapjco3.so file in the build process into the container java.library.path.

Can this be achieved in a quarkus-specific way?

Alternatively, I was thinking of using the quarkus base image and build a new image by adding the COPY command to copy the libsapjco3.so file. But how can this be integrated into the build process?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The alternate approach you propose is probably easier

Comment: Thank you @geoand. my second question to the alternate approach is how can this be achieved in a devops friendly way?

Comment: I can't really help with that

Comment: Actually the alternate approach worked. its just for me to be able to automate the process now. thanks a bunch @geoand once again.